# Get object void properties

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, pure-js

I get an object:
`const foo = {}`

And void this object like `foo.div.h2.span`
how in this object I could catch void parameters? It should be like: `object foo voided with div>h2>span` parameters?

a little bit more examples: 
 `Format.div("fqe");` // should returns  `"<div>fqe</div>"`

`Format.div.h1.span("FizBuz");`  should returns  `// "<div><h1><span>FizBuz</span></h1></div>"`

So, I need to catch in object with which parameters he was called

Comment: are you trying to get deep level properties? Please explain via a good example what you're trying to do?

Comment: Try to reword your question. As it currently written it is hard to say what you are trying to actually achieve. I don't think "void this object" makes any sense in context of javascript.